# Change citizenship while in L1b visa

Tags: visas, passports, dual-nationality

I've recently changed my nationality while on L1 visa, and my previous nationality doesn't allow double citizenship. I'll have to surrender my old passport.
Is it possible to transfer the visa from one passport to the other?
Anyone with such experience?

thank you.

Comment: This is probably a better question for [Expatriates.SE], but the details will depend on whether you will be inside the US or outside when you take your new citizenship and surrender your old passport.  In general the solution is just to get a new visa for your new passport, which you must do at a consulate outside the US, but you only need to do that of you are planning to leave and reenter the US anyway.

Comment: I'm actually in US and already accepted the citizenship since 3 months. And I haven't surrendered the passport yet.

Comment: Have you asked your company's attorneys? Since L-1B is sponsored by your company, you should keep them informed.

Comment: If your first country of citizenship provides that you automatically lost your citizenship by taking the other citizenship then it is probably fraudulent to use that passport. But since you're in the US, you don't need a visa. Visas are only for entering the US.  Your lawful presence in the US is signified by your I-94, whether it is a paper form or an electronic record. You should report your change of citizenship to USCIS.  Then, as noted by @krubo, you should tell your employer if you haven't already. The next time you leave the US, you can get a new visa for your new passport.